# how to download and clear entity framework data?

Tags: curated-data, entity

Firstly I want to know when executing queries like,

```
universalClass=EntityClass["Company",All];

derivedClass=FilteredEntityClass[
    universalClass,
    EntityFunction[c,StringLength[c["Name"]]<=2]
];

EntityValue[referer,"Entities"]
```

Will this query only download the information about entities of type `"Company"` which match the StringLength criterion or will it download for all the entities of type `"Company"` the property `"Name"` and then evaluate the query locally using my system resources and produce the resulting smaller set of entities. So the question is basically does the framework downloads all the required properties in the query and executes it locally and then produces the result or does it only download the data required to only present the final result while actual query execution happens on WolframAlpha servers.

Secondly, how do you prefetch all data of a particular entity type for both the Entity Framework and equivalent XXXData. Based on the information I found searching:

The following command clears the cache for EntityFramework:

```
Internal`ClearEntityValueCache[universalClass]
```

The following command downloads and caches the data for EntityFramework:

```
EntityPrefetch[universalClass]
```

Next to download and cache all the data for XXXData:

```
CompanyData[All,"Preload"]
```

Now what is the similar command to clear the cache for XXXData?

Also if there are other better ways of storing and clearing data for the EntityFramework or XXXData, please share.

Also what does the following command do?

```
CompanyData[All,"Install"]
```

What is the difference between install and preload?

The cached data from Entity Framework is stored in

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory,"Knowledgebase"}]
```

But where is the data from XXXData stored?